# 逆数和の不定方程式を解きたい

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Google Colaboratoryを使っています。

相異な自然数の逆数の和が１
`1/x_1 + 1/x_2 +‥‥+1/x_n = 1 (x_1>x_2>‥‥>x_n)`
自然数ｎのそれぞれの値に対する(x_1〜x_n)の組の個数や各組の`ｘ`について調べたいと思っています。

色々調べてみましたが逆数ゆえかエラーばかり吐かれてしまいます。
コードの例など教えてほしいです。

また相異な`ｘ`をa,b‥,ｚとして導入していましたが上記のように（x_1>x_2>‥‥>x_n)とするなど、うまい書き方は可能でしょうか。

##### 試した例１

エラーは出ませんでしたが、すべての解が求められていません

```py
for i in range(2, 999): 
 for j in range(i+1, 999):
  for k in range(j+1, 999):
   for l in range(k+1, 999):
     for m in range(l+1, 999):
      if 1/i + 1/j + 1/k + 1/l + 1/m == 1:
       print(i, j ,k ,l, m)
```

##### 例２

無効な構文と表示されます。

```py
import sympy as sym
from sympy.abc import a, b, c, d, e, n 
from sympy.solvers.diophantine import diophantine
  
f = sym.Eq(a**-1 + b**-1 + c**-1 + d**-1 + e**-1, n)
diophantine(f.subs(n, 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/fractions.html
python には有理数クラスってのがはじめからあるので
これを使うと無理数のでてこない計算はエラー誤差を気にせず正確にできます

```py
from fractions import Fraction

n = 5
results = []

# x_list のうち fix_index までを固定して残りの変数を変化させて検索
# rest_value はまだ決まってない項で使える合計値(有理数インスタンスを渡す)
def iter(x_list, fix_index, rest_value):
    if fix_index >= n: # 全部の変数が決まった
        if rest_value == 0: # １とぴったり一致した
            results.append(x_list[:]) # 副作用を受けないようにコピーして結果に追加
        return

    # 残りで使える値がすでにマイナスだったら検索終了
    if rest_value <= 0:
        return

    # 次の変数を決めて探索する
    # e.g. x1 x2 を固定 | x3 x4 x5 を変化させて探す場合を考える
    # x1 < x2 < x3 ... を仮定 (質問とは逆順だけど最大値不明なので 2からはじめてだんだん増やしていきたいから低い順に)
    # なので検索範囲最小値は x2 + 1 (x1 は１つ前がないので 2 から開始)
    min_x = x_list[fix_index - 1] + 1 if fix_index else 2
    # 最大値は 1/x3 + 1/x3 + 1/x3 > rest_value となる最大の x3
    # なぜなら x3 < x4 < x5 に対して 1/x3 + 1/x3 + 1/x3 > 1/x3 + 1/x4 + 1/x5 = rest_value
    # つまり x3 < (rest_value / 決まってない変数の数)の逆数 = 決まってない変数の数 / rest_value
    max_x = int((n - fix_index) / rest_value)
    for x in range(min_x, max_x + 1) :
        # x3 を決定して再度残りを検索する
        x_list[fix_index] = x
        iter(x_list, fix_index + 1, rest_value - Fraction(1,x)) # 1/x の有理数インスタンス


def main():
    x_list = [0] * n;
    iter(x_list, 0, Fraction(1)) # 最初は固定なしで全部の合計が 1 のものを検索
    print(results)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

実行結果

```
> python test.py
[[2, 3, 7, 43, 1806], [2, 3, 7, 44, 924], [2, 3, 7, 45, 630], [2, 3, 7, 46, 483], [2, 3, 7, 48, 336], [2, 3, 7, 49, 294], [2, 3, 7, 51, 238], [2, 3, 7, 54, 189], [2, 3, 7, 56, 168], [2, 3, 7, 60, 140], [2, 3, 7, 63, 126], [2, 3, 7, 70, 105], [2, 3, 7, 78, 91], [2, 3, 8, 25, 600], [2, 3, 8, 26, 312], [2, 3, 8, 27, 216], [2, 3, 8, 28, 168], [2, 3, 8, 30, 120], [2, 3, 8, 32, 96], [2, 3, 8, 33, 88], [2, 3, 8, 36, 72], [2, 3, 8, 40, 60], [2, 3, 8, 42, 56], [2, 3, 9, 19, 342], [2, 3, 9, 20, 180], [2, 3, 9, 21, 126], [2, 3, 9, 22, 99], [2, 3, 9, 24, 72], [2, 3, 9, 27, 54], [2, 3, 9, 30, 45], [2, 3, 10, 16, 240], [2, 3, 10, 18, 90], [2, 3, 10, 20, 60], [2, 3, 10, 24, 40], [2, 3, 11, 14, 231], [2, 3, 11, 15, 110], [2, 3, 11, 22, 33], [2, 3, 12, 13, 156], [2, 3, 12, 14, 84], [2, 3, 12, 15, 60], [2, 3, 12, 16, 48], [2, 3, 12, 18, 36], [2, 3, 12, 20, 30], [2, 3, 12, 21, 28], [2, 3, 14, 15, 35], [2, 4, 5, 21, 420], [2, 4, 5, 22, 220], [2, 4, 5, 24, 120], [2, 4, 5, 25, 100], [2, 4, 5, 28, 70], [2, 4, 5, 30, 60], [2, 4, 5, 36, 45], [2, 4, 6, 13, 156], [2, 4, 6, 14, 84], [2, 4, 6, 15, 60], [2, 4, 6, 16, 48], [2, 4, 6, 18, 36], [2, 4, 6, 20, 30], [2, 4, 6, 21, 28], [2, 4, 7, 10, 140], [2, 4, 7, 12, 42], [2, 4, 7, 14, 28], [2, 4, 8, 9, 72], [2, 4, 8, 10, 40], [2, 4, 8, 12, 24], [2, 4, 9, 12, 18], [2, 4, 10, 12, 15], [2, 5, 6, 8, 120], [2, 5, 6, 9, 45], [2, 5, 6, 10, 30], [2, 5, 6, 12, 20], [3, 4, 5, 6, 20]]
```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。
実行してみたところ、
`ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-da0fe8c92bdc> in <module>
     35 
     36 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 37     main()

<ipython-input-12-da0fe8c92bdc> in main()
     28 
     29 def main():
---> 30     n = int(sys.argv[1])
     31     x_list = [0] * n;
     32     iter(x_list, 0, Fraction(1)) # 最初は固定なしで全部の合計が 1 のものを検索

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-f'`

と、エラーが出てしまいました。何か問題があるのでしょうか...

Comment: x_n と変数が５個固定ではなく可変なのかなと思い第１引数に変数の個数を与えるようにしてました。google-colaboratoryは使ったことがないのでコマンドラインが与えられないなら n = int(sys.argv[1]) この部分に n = 5 とか入れちゃえばいいと思います

Comment: あと条件を読み違えていて同じ値はとらないんですね。range(x_list[fix_index - 1] の部分を +1 から始めれば同じ値になる検索をはじけると思います

Comment: + 1から始めるとは具体的にどういう事でしょうか。何度も申し訳ないです。

Comment: すでに回答は書き換え済みですが min_x = x_list[fix_index - 1] + 1 の +1 の部分です。以前のプログラムでは x1 x2 まできまってて x3 を決める際に x3 の検索を x2 と同じ値から始めてました。それを x2 +1 から始めると言う意味です、これで x2=x3 のケースが出てこなくなります。前のプログラム実行したということなので残ってたら見比べてみてください

Answer (score 0):

条件判定式の両辺に `i * j * k * l * m` を掛けた式で判定することにしました。整数なので精度の考慮は必要ありません。なお，

```
i < j < k < l < m
1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5 + 1/5 = 1
1/2 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 + 1/8 = 1
1/2 + 1/3 + 1/18 + 1/18 + 1/18 = 1
```

より，`i < 5, j < 8, k < 18` が成り立ちます。
これを使って計算時間を減らしましたが，うわさどおり（?） Python の for ループは遅いようで，試す場合は `stop = 100` から始めて徐々に増やすことをお勧めします。

```
stop = 100             # range() does not include 'stop'
# stop = 1000
nv = 5                 # number of variables(i, j, k, l, m)
stop_i = nv            # 1/i * nv > 1 -> i < nv
stop_j = (nv - 1) * 2  # 1/2 + 1/j * (nv - 1) > 1 -> j < (nv - 1) * 2
stop_k = (nv - 2) * 6  # 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/k * (nv - 2) > 1 -> k < (nv - 2) * 6

for i in range(2, stop_i):
    for j in range(i+1, stop_j):
        for k in range(j+1, stop_k):
            for l in range(k+1, stop):
                for m in range(l+1, stop):
                    if (j * k * l * m + i * k * l * m
                        + i * j * l * m + i * j * k * m
                        + i * j * k * l == i * j * k * l * m):
                        print(f'{i:4d} {j:4d} {k:4d} {l:4d} {m:4d}')
```

```
   2    3    7   78   91
   2    3    8   32   96
   2    3    8   33   88
   2    3    8   36   72
   2    3    8   40   60
   2    3    8   42   56
   2    3    9   22   99
   2    3    9   24   72
   2    3    9   27   54
   2    3    9   30   45
   2    3   10   18   90
   2    3   10   20   60
   2    3   10   24   40
   2    3   11   22   33
   2    3   12   14   84
   2    3   12   15   60
   2    3   12   16   48
   2    3   12   18   36
   2    3   12   20   30
   2    3   12   21   28
   2    3   14   15   35
   2    4    5   28   70
   2    4    5   30   60
   2    4    5   36   45
   2    4    6   14   84
   2    4    6   15   60
   2    4    6   16   48
   2    4    6   18   36
   2    4    6   20   30
   2    4    6   21   28
   2    4    7   12   42
   2    4    7   14   28
   2    4    8    9   72
   2    4    8   10   40
   2    4    8   12   24
   2    4    9   12   18
   2    4   10   12   15
   2    5    6    9   45
   2    5    6   10   30
   2    5    6   12   20
   3    4    5    6   20
```

（追記，御参考）
**numba** モジュールの導入（`pip install numba`）により計算時間の短縮を試みました。私の環境（macOS 13(M1), Python 3.10.8, numba 0.56.4）では，`stop = 1000` で約40分の1に短縮できました。

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def rp_search(stp_i, stp_j, stp_k, stp_l, stp_m):
    rslt = []
    for i in range(2, stp_i):
        for j in range(i+1, stp_j):
            for k in range(j+1, stp_k):
                for l in range(k+1, stp_l):
                    for m in range(l+1, stp_m):
                        if (j * k * l * m + i * k * l * m
                            + i * j * l * m + i * j * k * m
                            + i * j * k * l == i * j * k * l * m):
                            rslt.append([i, j, k, l, m])
    return rslt


stop = 1000
nv = 5                 # number of variables
stop_i = nv
stop_j = (nv - 1) * 2
stop_k = (nv - 2) * 6

result = rp_search(stop_i, stop_j, stop_k, stop, stop)

for r in result:
    print(f'{r[0]:4d} {r[1]:4d} {r[2]:4d} {r[3]:4d} {r[4]:4d}')
```

Comment: 返信ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。